# Installing mysql on mac snow leopard Mac OS X 10.6.8 error

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos

I'm a newbie to Django and I want to run it not with SQLite but with my current MySQL database set up through PHP. However, I am coding mainly on a Mac (the bane of my developer existence) and I have run into a problem with running:

```
python setup.py build
```

from my MySQL-python-1.2.4b4 folder and it's giving me the following error. I have tried Googling for the solution but most results show an error with XCode4 for Mac OS Lion or Mountain Lion and I'm running Snow Leopard. The results I found for Snow Leopard doesn't work either.

```
running develop

running egg_info

writing MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

writing manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

running build_ext

building '_mysql' extension

gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,4,'beta',4) -D__version__=1.2.4b4 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/_mysql.o -g -Os -arch x86_64 -fno-common -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL

unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory

error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: What does `xcodebuild -version` show?

Comment: It shows: -bash: xcodebuild: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention that `xcodebuild` is not found, the most likely explanation is that you have not yet installed a version of `Xcode` which includes various build tools, like the `gcc` C compiler needed to build the C extension module included in `MySQL-python`.  Since you are running on OS X 10.6, Snow Leopard, the most recent version of Xcode for 10.6 that includes `gcc-4.2` is `Xcode 3.2.6` which you can download without cost from the Apple Developer site after free registration.  See, for example, the directions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25097/how-can-i-obtain-older-versions-of-xcode).  Unfortunately, the download is very large.  (More recent releases of Xcode for more recent OS X releases are packaged in smaller pieces but they are not supported on 10.6.)  The good news is: you'll only have to do it once since Xcode for 10.6 is not likely to ever be updated again!

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I'm getting a Thinkpad for myself for Christmas this year.